# How to add request headers to outboundGateway spring integration dsl

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I couldn't find a function to add headers to outboundGateway in spring integration dsl.

```
.handle(outboundGateway("localhost:8080/search")
       .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
       .expectedResponseType(Order.class))
```

The headers that i would like to add to request are

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(newArrayList(APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.add("Client-Id", "test");
```

Can someone help me here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct: Spring Integration doesn't allow to manipulate `HttpHeaders` object directly. Instead you should follow the canonical messaging approach - protocol free `.enrichHeaders()`:

```
.enrichHeaders(e -> e
                        .header(DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .header(DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .header("Client-Id", "test"))
.handle(outboundGateway("localhost:8080/search")
   .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
   .expectedResponseType(Order.class))
```

Comment: Sorry it didnt work these headers are not passed to the client, my wiremock complained saying "Header is not present" to match to the stub.

Comment: I made it to work by adding `.mappedRequestHeaders("Client-Id", DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.ACCEPT, DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.CONTENT_TYPE)` to outboundGateway

Comment: Or you can use `*`. Sorry, been busy, but glad that you have figured out without the help!

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help, i dont want to use * as i have some flow header variables which i don't want to send to client